# Añadir background color a etiqueta de un marcador en google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

tengo un marcador en google maps con una etiqueta como esta:

```
    label: {
    text: label,
    color: '#012294',
    fontFamily: 'monospace',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
},
```

He intentado diversas maneras pero no logro configurarle un color de fondo a la etiqueta

Comment: con marcador te refieres al popup que aparece al dar click en un pin? o a pin como tal? o a que cosa?

Comment: sin dar click, al texto de la etiqueta que aparece a simple vista

Answer (score 0):

Pues solo me salta a la mente los marcadores que agregas con

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Si es el caso, no es posible editarlos mucho que digamos, el popup que aparece al darles click si se puede personalizar pero el pin/marcador generado no.

Lo mas cercano seria

```
#id_de_contenerdor_mapa img{background:red}
```

Comment: No me dio resultado, google lo hace dificl a esta simple configuracion, de todas formas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Sé que la pregunta es vieja, pero lo que quieres o querías hacer lo puedes conseguir personalizando el estilo de la clase `.popup-bubble`.

```
/* The popup bubble styling. */
.popup-bubble {
  /* Position the bubble centred-above its parent. */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  /* Style the bubble. */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Este ejemplo es el estilo por default que trae. Para más información puedes ir al siguiente enlace: [Custom Popups](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup#maps_overlay_popup-css).